# rails polymorphic model implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

In my project, I have a relationship model that allow users to follow each other.

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :followed, :class_name => "User"

end
```

Now, I want to also allow users to follow courses and groups. Do I start a new followedCourse and followedGroup model or do I make the relationship model polymorphic? How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use polymorphic for potentially-large tables. I think the best way to go is to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships for this kind of relation.

Remember to create indexes on user_id, group_id to speed up things a bit. You can do that by using `add_index(:table_name,[:user_id,:group_id])`.

I would also make the relation UNIQUE, which you can do appending `:unique => true` at the end of the `add_index` command.

Comment: forgot to link you to a `has_and_belongs_to_many` proper explanation. Here it goes: [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

Comment: Thanks Lucas, that solved my problem. And I was reading about it at the rails guides. But your link is even more helpful! :)

Comment: One question though, i need to follow and unfollow specific courses&groups. But I won't have a model for that. Do I just use user model to do that? Like:   `def following?(followed)
    courses_users.find_by_user_id(followed)
  end`

Comment: exactly! In this case you want to ask an `User` if he follows a course. You're following the right path!

Comment: and since an `User` `has_and_belongs_to_many :courses` you can ask if he follows a course this way: `User.new.courses.include?(course_instance)`

Comment: i think i got a new problem here. since the courses are created by the users, it already belongs_to user. so when I use user.courses after I add has_and_belongs_to_many, it is in conflict with the user.courses method from before.

Comment: I've used `has_and_belongs_to_many :followed_courses,  :class_name => "Course"` looks like working. :)